# Suppress <script src= ...> from Rmarkdown html output

Tags: javascript, r-markdown

Is there an option to suppress the large  tag in the head of html outputs of Rstudio .rmd documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `standalone: no` option; it means that your document won't be readable offline though.

```
---
output: 
  html_document: 
    self_contained: no
---
```

Still, this will output a 3.8MB directory because basic rmarkdown templates inclue bootstrap.js; one could use alternate templates to reduce their size, for instance one of [hrbmstr's markdowntemplates](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/markdowntemplates):

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/markdowntemplates")
```

In the Rmd file:

```
---
output: markdowntemplates::bulma

---
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, the size of the folders created is still a whopping 3.6MB even for a simple Hello World html page. I am looking for a way to reduce the "overhead" (css, js, bootstrap, etc.) substantially even if I lose some of the nice formatting.

Comment: Ok, sorry i misunderstood the question. Then you need to find a Rmd template that doesn't use bootstrap (since it's 3.6 out of the 3.8MB). Here is a solution: https://rud.is/b/2016/02/04/alternate-r-markdown-templates/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful. I have hopes now that RStudio will offer a few smaller templates as well in the near future.

Comment: In particular, I would very much like a light-weight template which preserves the code color scheme, which none of the package ones seem to do?